# How to get input of Html editor in textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, rich-text-editor

Please I'm working on a project to make html editor.
I downloaded a program online trying to modify it to my need, I'm having difficulty to get the inner html of the edit using javascript or jquery output it in `textarea and input type` so I can save it to my database. It only shows the output in html element but not in textarea.

**MORE EXPLANATION OF WHAT I NEED**

1. 1 when I key text in the editor I want it to return the in a hidden
   textarea.
2. 2 I want to be able to save the in my database.
3. 3 I want the editor the have default text to display LIKE `[please
   start typing your code here]`

Please this is what have been giving me trouble to complete my work
I will appreciate if anyone can help me or suggest another method or program to use in archive this.
Thank you guys here is the program

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.7/styles/monokai_sublime.min.css">
<style class="cp-pen-styles">.ace-md{
  height: 300px;
}</style>

<div ng-app="app" class="container-fluid">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl" class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Markdown Editor</h1>

      <div ace-code-editor class="ace-md"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Markdown Preview</h1>
      <div markdown-viewer></div>
<input type="text" markdown-viewer id="outpt-hm"></input>
<--!<textarea markdown-viewer id="outpt-hm"> TRY TO UNCOMMENT THIS AND SEE THE RESULT</textarea>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**J QUERY-LIBERY TO MAKE IT WORK**

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.7/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.0/ace.min.js"></script>
```

**J QUERY SCRIPT**

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', [
    '$scope',
    function ($scope) {
        ace.config.set('basePath', '//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.0/');
    }
]);
app.directive('aceCodeEditor', [function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.editor = ace.edit(element[0]);
                scope.editor.getSession().setMode('ace/mode/markdown');
                scope.editor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');
                scope.editor.getSession().on('change', function (e) {
                    scope.$emit('ace.editor.change');
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
app.directive('markdownViewer', [function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$on('ace.editor.change', function () {
                    element.html(marked(scope.editor.getValue()));
                    element.find('pre code').each(function (i, block) {
                        hljs.highlightBlock(block);
                    });
                    element.find('table').addClass('table');
                });
            }
        };
    }]);//HERE I TRY USING JAVASRCIPT BUT IT DIDN'T WORK  //document.getElementById('outpt-hm').value = getElementsByClassName("ace_text-input").innerHTML;  </script>
```

Comment: @daniel is there no any other way to archive this please i really need it to get done my work i have no time to learn it now but sure i will do in future

Comment: why do you need a class in a `<style>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could try changing the `markdownViewer` piece of code like this - if you see an alert and the data is what you expect then you can use that value however you like. This is not tested, having never seen the editor before.

```
app.directive('markdownViewer', [function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$on('ace.editor.change', function () {

                var data=scope.editor.getValue();
                alert( 'If you see data here then you can do stuff with it!!!\n\n'+data );

                element.html(marked(data));
                element.find('pre code').each(function (i, block) {
                    hljs.highlightBlock(block);
                });
                element.find('table').addClass('table');
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

HTML form elements ( some of, not all ) can have a `placeholder` value - the default value viewed when looking at the form - though it is not the actual `value` of the field.

examples:

```
<textarea id='bob' name='bob' cols=80 rows=10 placeholder='The placeholder text here'></textarea>

<input type='text' id='sue' name='sue' placeholder='another placeholder' />
```

You might find it handly to have additions in your stylesheet also.

```
<style>
    ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
        font-size:1em;
        font-style:italic;
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       color:black
    }
    :focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{ 
        color:transparent;
    }
    :-moz-placeholder {
        font-size:1em;
        font-style:italic;
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       color:black 
    }
    :focus:-moz-placeholder{
        color:transparent;
    }
    ::-moz-placeholder {
        font-size:1em;
        font-style:italic;
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       color:black
    }
    :focus::-moz-placeholder {
        color:transparent;
    }
    :-ms-input-placeholder {
        font-size:1em;
        font-style:italic;
        font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
       color:black
    }
    :focus:-ms-input-placeholder {  
        color:transparent;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It worked this is pretty good but the default message solution not solved

Comment: The default message? I presume you mean `placeholder`?

Comment: Do i need to do it this way to get it inside the textare `element.value(outpt-hm(data));` or `document.getElementById('outpt-hm').value = data` ?

Comment: whichever works - the latter is probably just as easy so go for that

Comment: I go for this and it worked 1document.getElementById('outpt-hm').value = data`

Comment: I did this to get the return the input from textarea to the editor if type in textarea but didn't work how can i do this `data.html = document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').value;` and 'data.value= document.getElementById('inputTextToSave').value;' @RamRaider

Comment: @RamRaider it's a good practice to surround all HTML attributes with quotes, and remind that old IE browsers do not support `placeholder` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

I’ve been using this component for my projects:

```
<html>
<script src="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jsuites.net/v5/jsuites.css" type="text/css" />

<div id="editor" style="width: 480px;"></div>

<p><input type='button' value='Get data' id="btn"></p>

<script>
let editor = jSuites.editor(document.getElementById('editor'), {
    allowToolbar: true,
    value: '<b>This is a basic example...</b><br><br><br><br>'
});

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert(editor.getData())
})
</script>
</html>
```

Here's the link if you're interested: https://jsuites.net/docs/javascript-html-editor